# How to check existence of environment variables at compile time in Visual Studio 2017 C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, environment-variables, compile-time

I would like to check at compile-time whether an environment variable exists and I can't find a way to do it.

The reason is code maintainability: I use QT and I created an environment variable that points to the root installation directory, to be used for referencing headers and libraries.
So when some years later I or a colleague of mine checks out the project and tries to compile it I want to throw a custom comprehensive error message along the lines of `please install QT version XYZ and create environment variable QT_PATH to point at the root directory`.

I know that a readme file is the proper way of doing it and I am creating that one as well, but I still want to know if it is generally possible to check for the existence of environment variables at compile time.

The closest I've gotten so far is using a preprocessor definition `QT_INSTALLATION_PATH=$(QT_PATH);` and checking it with

```
#if QT_INSTALLATION_PATH == '\0'
#error "..."
#endif
```

which throws an `expression expected` error if QT_PATH doesn't exist and works fine if it does exist.

Comment: did you try just adding reference to this environment variable in additional compiler/linker flags?

Comment: No, how do I do that?

Comment: It would be a good idea to avoid environment variables instead.

Comment: Then what is the proper way to reference stuff from bundles like QT or OpenCV? Should I just copy everything into my project?

Comment: *"check at compile-time whether an environment variable exists"*, it would be at build time, in your toolchain.

Comment: What's the difference between compiling and building?

Comment: Compiling is just the process of compiling, building is the full process, from VS solution generation in some cases, to linking.

Comment: I see. Of course I'd be fine with a pre-compile-time answer as well. :-)

Comment: Well, that's my answer, pre-compile is before the solution exists or by adding precompile steps. But don't do that, generators are supposed to do these checks, that's why they were created.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do so is to use Visual Studio generators that will do these checks for you before compilation time.

For instance, CMake does this really well and can select specific versions of Qt or OpenCV. Qt itself comes with QMake, but I suggest you aim for a common generator (not sure QMake supports OpenCV), which is CMake.

Comment: I would like to do it inside Visual Studio. If CMake tells me about it before I even have a VS project file then that's not what I'm looking for, because I'd like VS to tell me.

Comment: That's the point, CMake will generate the proper VS solution for your version of VS (don't forget that in a few years, your new user will have to migrate the solution, leading to all lots of pains if you don't provide a way to regenearte it) with the Qt and OpenCV version that the user has. That's how it's done. What you want to do is a hack, that's not how you do these checks properly.

Comment: Cmake is not really a part of the company's toolchain, so I'll try to find alternative answers, too, but thanks anyway. The downvote wasn't me btw.

Comment: In that case, try using QMake. If you have Qt, then you have QMake. You may need to port the equivalent FindOpenCV from CMake to QMake to have similar checks.